# bundler: Using a custom path while using system gems is unsupported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab, bundler, gitlab-ci

I am using `GitLab-CI/CD` to build my `Rails` application. I have noticed my builds are failing due to `Using a custom path while using system gems is unsupported` error, which were working perfectly fine before.

Tried to check newer update releases but didn't find any issues. Does any one have any idea on recent updates or somthing on mentioned issue?

Bellow is my `gitlab-ci.yml`

```
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

cache:
  key: ${CI_JOB_NAME}
  paths:
    - vendor/ruby

before_script:
    - apt-get update -qq
    - ruby -v
    - which ruby
    - gem --version
    - git --version
    - gem update --system 2.7.6
    - gem install bundler -v 2.0.1
    - bundle -v
    - bundle config ${REPO_URL} ${BUNDLE_GITLAB__TOKEN}
    - bundle config --global disable_shared_gems true
    - bundle install --jobs $(nproc)  "${FLAGS[@]}" --path vendor 

rubocop:
  tags:
    - rubocop
  script:
    - bundle exec rubocop

# rspec:
#   stage: test
#   script:
#     - bundle exec rspec
```

And bellow is the brief error I'm getting

```
$ apt-get update -qq
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-linux]
$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
$ gem --version
3.0.3
$ git --version
git version 2.20.1
$ gem update --system 2.7.6
Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.7.6
Installing RubyGems 2.7.6
Bundler 1.16.1 installed
RubyGems 2.7.6 installed
Regenerating binstubs



------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RubyGems installed the following executables:
    /usr/local/bin/gem
    /usr/local/bin/bundle

RubyGems system software updated
$ gem install bundler -v 2.0.1
Successfully installed bundler-2.0.1
1 gem installed
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 2.0.1
$ bundle config https://gitlab.com/dharshannn/test-star.git ${BUNDLE_GITLAB__TOKEN}
$ bundle config --global disable_shared_gems true
$ bundle install --jobs $(nproc)  "${FLAGS[@]}" --path vendor
Using a custom path while using system gems is unsupported.

path:
Set for your local app (/usr/local/bundle/config): "vendor"

path.system:
Set via BUNDLE_PATH__SYSTEM: true

disable_shared_gems:
Set for the current user (/root/.bundle/config): true
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Have the exact same issue since today. My CI-config file didn't contain the added bundle configuration statement `bundle config --global disable_shared_gems true`. If that is removed the CI will fail with the following message. `You have not configured a value for \`disable_shared_gems\``

Comment: This *just* started happening to us also last night on Gitlab, with no changes to our system. Does anyone know _why_ this is happening?

Comment: It looks like `BUNDLE_PATH__SYSTEM=true` was [added recently](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/commit/e040029c82501556371e9d84a9db607dfb1bba51#diff-74bcd4eb147d76d56d72bb7b43848b20) to the Dockerfile of the official `ruby` image. The changes [has been reverted](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/commit/4e90a92eb25fd7527f8eb5b6cede5f217f93ab57#diff-74bcd4eb147d76d56d72bb7b43848b20) but no images seem to have been rebuild and published yet with this fix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The same happened to me today. I am pretty sure that there was no update to `bundler` or `gem`. The Docker image however has been updated (I was using `ruby:2.6.3`). I also added a new dependency when this started happening, so I suspect it was dependent on a gem which was already installed in the system path thus the error message.

You can get around it by specifying the following configuration variables in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
  BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "true"
  BUNDLE_PATH__SYSTEM: "false"
```

This will configure Bundler to not use shared gems and disable system gems fully.

See https://bundler.io/v2.0/bundle_config.html

> disable_shared_gems (BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS): Stop Bundler from accessing gems installed to RubyGems' normal location.

and

> path.system (BUNDLE_PATH__SYSTEM): Whether Bundler will install gems into the default system path (Gem.dir).

Comment: Thanks for this. Of note, I use Drone and I added these in the `environment` setting in my pipeline, and now I'm back to non-failing builds.