# Using a custom path while using system gems is unsupported

Tags: ruby, bundler, gitlab-ci

Gitlab CI bundle install giving unexpected error. It was working perfectly fine till yesterday evening.

Referred to below solution but issue still persist:

[bundler: Using a custom path while using system gems is unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57005779/bundler-using-a-custom-path-while-using-system-gems-is-unsupported)

stages:
  - test

cache:
  key: test-app-cache
  paths:
    - vendor/

variables:
  BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "true"
  BUNDLE_PATH__SYSTEM: "false"

deploy:
  stage: test
  image: "ruby:2.5"
  script:
    - gem update system
    - gem install bundler -v 2.0.1
    - bundle config --global disable_shared_gems true
    - bundle install --path vendor

Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for test-app-cache-9...
FATAL: file does not exist
Failed to extract cache
$ gem update system
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
$ gem install bundler -v 2.0.1
Successfully installed bundler-2.0.1
1 gem installed
$ bundle config --global disable_shared_gems true
You have a bundler environment variable for disable_shared_gems set to "true". This will take precedence over the global value you are setting
$ bundle install --path vendor
Using a custom path while using system gems is unsupported.

path:
Set for your local app (/usr/local/bundle/config): "vendor"
Set via BUNDLE_PATH: "/usr/local/bundle"

path.system:
Set via BUNDLE_PATH__SYSTEM: true

disable_shared_gems:
Set via BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: true
Set for the current user (/root/.bundle/config): true
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1

Comment: You are much more likely to get an answer if you ask a specific question, format your console output, explain how exactly the error occurs, and explain what you have done to resolve this issue on your own.

Comment: Currently digging into this now as well. Pretty sure it ties in with the release of debian buster (which our docker images clicked onto, as we don't specify the OS version in our base image tage).